# How to include external WAV files in  Android

Tags: android, audio, storage, external, wav

A few WAV files used by my app are currently located in `res/raw`. These files need to be accessible by the user after the app is installed. So ideally my app should create a folder on the device and put the files in it. Any idea/suggestions on how to do this?

```
soundIds[0] = soundPool.load(test2Activity, R.raw.snare, 1);
        soundIds[1] = soundPool.load(test2Activity, R.raw.snare2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the sd_card, so you can create a directory and put there your files

```
// create a File object for the parent directory
File yourDirectory = new File("/sdcard/YourDirectory/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
yourDirectory.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(yourDirectory, filename);
// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

The output file should be your sound that you have loaded from res/raw.
My advice would be to just copy the sound to the folder, and still use the sound from res/raw from within your app because

1) it is easier since you can access it as a resources

2) you are sure the user didn't deleted the directory.

Remember to put the user permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest

Comment: great thanks ill give that a try. i need it so the user can edit the sound and the app will use that.

Comment: @user1033558 filaneme is a String. Look at what javadocs says.
Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29 to read the resource

Comment: those dev docs are too alien for me to use atm. there is never any folder or file created with your code.

Comment: this works thanks File myDir=new File("/sdcard/mydir");
             myDir.mkdirs();
             File file = new File (myDir, "R.raw.snare");
             if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    /// add coding here what do u want to save.. 
                    
                    out.write((int) file.getTotalSpace());
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }